# Convert TTS async initialization to synchronous

Tags: java, android, concurrency, text-to-speech

I need to retrieve some information from the TTS engine, however the engine requires initialization before using. I know that `TextToSpeech` will call `onInit` to notify it's done.

I have created this helper class to turn that into a synchronous call:

```
public class PureTTSHelper implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    TextToSpeech tts;
    boolean ready;
    CompletableFuture<TextToSpeech> completableFuture;

    public PureTTSHelper(Context ctx){
        this.ready = false;
        this.tts = new TextToSpeech(ctx, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int i) {
        ready = true;
        completableFuture.complete(tts);
    }

    public TextToSpeech getTTSSync(){
        if(ready){
            return tts;
        }

        completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

        try {
            return completableFuture.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
TextToSpeech tts = new PureTTSHelper(this).getTTSSync();
```

This doesn't work. What I believe is happening is that the thread is blocked on `return completableFuture.get()` and never got a chance to execute `completableFuture.complete(tts)`, however I am not very familiar with how concurrency works in Java so I am not sure if that is the exact reason.

Nevertheless, I have absolutely no idea how to make this work. Any ideas are welcome.

---

#### Edit

It seems that the initialization isn't exactly as asynchronous as I thought. The code

```
TextToSpeech tts = new PureTTSHelper(this).getTTSSync();
```

is executed in the activity's `onCreate` and the `TextToSpeech` object will not be initialized until the `onCreate` method returns.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple interface to get the callback from OnInit?

Comment: @brandall What do you mean by that?

Comment: The initialisation of a TTS object is Asynchronous, there is nothing you can do to alter that behaviour. Rather than blocking until OnInit is called, just implement the interface in your Activity and continue your code logic once you get the callback - checking of course for success or error

Comment: @brandall Thanks for the idea. At first I would like a synchronous solution because that would simplify the code but based on the tests it seems to be impossible. I ended up creating an async dependency system that would perform all the async tasks before executing the main code.

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction is to solve this problem by using a `CountDownLatch` initialized with a count of `1`.

```
public class PureTTSHelper implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    TextToSpeech tts;
    CountDownLatch latch;

    public PureTTSHelper(Context ctx){
        this.latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        this.tts = new TextToSpeech(ctx, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int i) {
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public TextToSpeech getTTSSync(){
        try {
            latch.await();
            return tts;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO
        }
    }
}
```

I have never worked with `TextToSpeech`; hopefully I got the semantics of its initialization right.

Comment: Wouldn't this suffer from the same problem? Your solution seems to simply use a CountDownLatch instead of a CompletableFuture.

Comment: I suppose I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I assume that the `TextToSpeech` constructor spawns some other thread to do the async work, in which case this solution will either (a) sit at `latch.await()` until `onInit()` happens or (b) return immediately since `onInit()` has already happened.

Comment: The problem is that when I put anything that blocks the thread in `getTTSSync`, `onInit` does not get executed. I'm not sure how TextToSpeech is implemented either.